# Add java web service project as dependency to another java client project using maven

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have created a web service and client project as well. Now I need the SEI created in web application to finish client application by taking the dependency of web application using maven. It didn't work. Can some one help me on this?

Client pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dstyle.orderapp</groupId>
<artifactId>OrderProcessingApplicationClient</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>OrderProcessingApplicationClient</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>

   <!-- using the web app as a dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.dstyle.orderapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>OrderProcessingApplication</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> 

</dependencies>
```

Web service application pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dstyle.orderapp</groupId>
<artifactId>OrderProcessingApplication</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>OrderProcessingApplication Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>OrderProcessingApplication</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: Please elaborate! How do you know that it does not work? Are there any messages you could share? Are you using eclipse with m2e or mvn on the command line?

Comment: I got below error when I do the mvn clean install

OrderProcessingApplicationClient: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.dstyle.orderapp:OrderProcessingApplicationCl
ient:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.dstyle.orderapp:OrderProcessingApplication:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not declare a dependency on a project that is packaged as a ***Web Archive*** (war file).

So if your *OrderProcessingApplication* module is nothing but a set of APIs you would use into other projects/modules, it should be configured in a manner it is packaged as a ***Java Archive***. This will send the built artifact (should be *OrderProcessingApplication-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*) to your local repository which will make it availble as a dependency for other projects.

So change your *OrderProcessingApplication* pom.xml file as follows:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.dstyle.orderapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>OrderProcessingApplication</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>OrderProcessingApplication Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>OrderProcessingApplication</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Then issue an `mvn clean install` on that project and go back to your client project and check that the dependency is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first run `mvn install` in OrderProcessingApplication to have it in your local maven repository, before mvn can find it as dependency of OrderProcessingApplicationClient.

Comment: I had alreay done that didn't work. Still getting same error. I checked my local repository it had created only a war file. 
what I am missing here?

Comment: Look at tmarwen's answer. A library must use packaging jar to be used as a dependency. I had not noticed that packaging was war.

Comment: Thank,
your answer was helpful.